# Splicing does not work when `map()` is nested inside of `mutate()`

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to take a column of index vectors and splice them into a `pluck()` call to get the value at those indexes.  It works fine if I do that in a `map()` call at the top level, but it does not recognize `.x` argument when the `map()` is called inside of a `mutate()`.  Can anyone explain why?  Is there a syntax I am missing?

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(purrr)

lst <-
    list(a=1, b=list(c=2, d=3))
str(lst)
#> List of 2
#>  $ a: num 1
#>  $ b:List of 2
#>   ..$ c: num 2
#>   ..$ d: num 3

#;; Note what is at index c(2L, 2L)
lst[[c(2L, 2L)]]
#> [1] 3

#;; Put that index in a dataframe column.
idx_df <-
    tibble(idx=list(c(2L, 2L)))
idx_df
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   idx      
#>   <list>   
#> 1 <int [2]>


#;; This does not work, but I expect it to, as I believe it should work
#;; analagously to what is below.
tryCatch({
    idx_df |>
        mutate(val = map_dbl(idx, ~ pluck(lst, !!!.x)))
}
, error=\(e) e)
#> <simpleError in quos(..., .ignore_empty = "all"): object '.x' not found>


#;; This works, but I should be able to do this in a mutate call.
idx_df$val <-
    map_dbl(idx_df$idx, ~ pluck(lst, !!!.x))
idx_df
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   idx         val
#>   <list>    <dbl>
#> 1 <int [2]>     3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It seems that the splicing operator is evaluated too early in this case. Try adding a `browser()` before the `pluck` call, it still fails. Therefore I think that `!!!` is either evaluated before `.x` is evaluated or something with the calling environment is messed up. Unfortunately, I don't have any more insights.

Comment: A rather ugly way to circumvent the problem is to use `do.call` instead of `!!!`: `idx_df %>% mutate(val = map_dbl(idx, ~do.call("pluck", c(list(lst), .x))))`

Comment: @starja Thanks!  I should have considered this, both the debugging and the `do.call()` solution.  Keeping this in my back pocket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As highlighted, problem seems to be when `!!!` is evaluated. As a simple workaround, you could create an interim function so that `!!!` isn't evaluated until the function is called:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lst <-
  list(a=1, b=list(c=2, d=3))

idx_df <-
  tibble(idx=list(c(2L, 2L)))

pluck_loc <-  function(x) {
  pluck(lst, !!!x)
}

idx_df |>
  mutate(val = map_dbl(idx, pluck_loc))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   idx         val
#>   <list>    <dbl>
#> 1 <int [2]>     3
```

Comment: Thanks!  This will work perfectly for my situation.  I am now wondering if there is a way to do this with the `enquo()` /`enquos()` work.  But at this point, I'll reserve that for a deeper learning dive, as your solution is great.  The only benefit to finding a `enquo()` type solution would be to not create a function name at the global level, but exchanging it for a more complicated anonymous function call...

Comment: I was scratching my head over that sort of approach for a while. Would be useful to find a way of delaying that part - do post another answer if you ever find a tidy way to do it!